# if-statement depending on input

Tags: python, input

I am trying to create a "simple" way to ask a person what shape they would like to find the area of. Then find the area of the shape based on their input. I am using Python 2.7.3. Here is what I have so far:

```
from math import pi
c = ""
r = ""
x = (input("Do you have a [r]ectangle or a [c]ircle? ")) # Answer with r or c
if x == "r":
    l = (int(input("What is the length of your rectangle? ")))
    w = (int(input("What is the width of your rectangle? ")))
    print( l * w )
elif x == "c":
    r = (int(input("What is the radius of your circle? ")))
    print( r ** 2 * pi)
else:
    print("Please enter request in lower case. ")
```

Comment: You have everything functioning fine. Just a couple unnecessary variables like you don't need `c = ""` and `r = ""` and you should add `.lower()` to the end of your `input` so that upper case responses are still accepted

Comment: I just do not understand why I received a -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from math import pi
# use raw input (raw_input()) for the inputs... input() is essentially eval(input())
# this is how i would ask for input for a simple problem like this
x = (raw_input("Do you have a [r]ectangle or a [c]ircle? ")) # Answer with r or c
# use .lower() to allow upper or lowercase
if x.lower() == "r":
    l = (int(raw_input("What is the length of your rectangle? ")))
    w = (int(raw_input("What is the width of your rectangle? ")))
    print( l * w )
elif x.lower() == "c":
    r = (int(raw_input("What is the radius of your circle? ")))
    print( r ** 2 * pi)
else:
    print("You didn't enter r or c.")
```

Comment: Do try to make a habit of not just posting code, but also giving a sentence or 2 explanation.

Comment: @Dukeling explanation is in comments in code

Comment: Quite some parentheses can be removed from this code. Not that it's wrong to have them there, just redundant.